# using scanner in java error: variable age might not have been initialized

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Age {

public static void main(String []args) {

System.out.println("Enter Your Age: ");

int age;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
in.nextInt();

if(age<18)
{
   System.out.println("You Can't Vote");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("You Can Vote Now");
}
} 
}
```

Compiler gives error during compile plz solve any one.

error: variable age might not have been initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler is complaining that you haven't initialized age and you are further using it (comparing in if condition). So instead of:

```
in.nextInt();
```

Use

```
age = in.nextInt();
```

Comment: vrevious i had,,,...  done this... age = in.nextInt();  but not work....  i think .. previous has different problems,,,,,,,

Answer (score 2):

age variable is not initialized, the way for initialize this is:

age = in.nextInt();

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Age {

public static void main(String []args) {
int age;

System.out.println("Enter Your Age: ");

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
age = in.nextInt();

if(age<18)
{
   System.out.println("You Can't Vote");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("You Can Vote Now");
}
} 
}
```